# connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh

While installing hadoop in my local machine , i got following error

```
ssh -vvv localhost 
OpenSSH_5.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e-fips 6 Sep 2011 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config    
debug1: Applying options for * 
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0 
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22. 
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused 
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

can some one help me to resolve this error , than changing port number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My port number is different. i tried using

```
ssh localhost -p 8088
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 156):

If install Hadoop on Mac OSX, make sure turn on **Remote Login** under **System Preferences** then **File Sharing**. This worked on my machine.

[image: Remote Login]

Comment: FYI, this worked for me to solve this error in genral (for future users) seemingly has nothing to do specifically with Hadoop.  Thanks!

Answer (score 121):

1. Remove SSH with the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
   ```
2. Install SSH again with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
   ```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Even though the answer sounds weird it works perfect even on port 22.

Comment: Why would it be necessary to remove it? If it was there the problem wouldn't exist.

Comment: I think the reason is its not properly installed before

Comment: Note that @Michael Z s answer below solves the problem by taking the second step only (i.e. install w/out uninstalling the whole thing; this adds features)

Comment: @patrick the remove process is needed in  case it's partially added or not in a consistent stage.

Comment: when I execute the first line, it show that openssh-server has not been installed. Maybe this is the reason of the problem.

Comment: yes @JasonZhou in that case you need to just install openssh-server. no, need to follow whole process

Comment: Just wanted to say that on WSL this messes up your ssh and you can't install it anymore

Comment: @Mike what do you mean by WSL?

Comment: @DivyangShah Windows Subsystem for Linux

Comment: This is ridiculous - after 4 hours, just needed reinstalled. I'll be writing up an article.

Comment: @Leafyshark yes, you should write. it will be helpful for others

Comment: try restarting the sshd service using "sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart", this should help and also keep all your ssh keys intact.

Answer (score 40):

Do you have `sshd` installed? You can verify that with:

```
which ssh
which sshd
```

For detailed information you can visit [this link](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-setup-and-configure-ssh-on-ubuntu.html#.UcvbF0AW38t).

Comment: i tried giving sudo apt-get install openssh-server command , it started to ask password for hduser , where i didnt create any password for the user, how i can know the default password

Comment: i tired which ssh , which sshd , this gives me the internal path '/usr/bin/ssh' , they are already installed in my machine

Comment: ssh is the client and sshd is the server. To install `sshd` use `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`. When you created the user account for  `hduser`, you must have created a password. Do not confuse that with the empty passphrase you might have set for passwordless ssh from the `hduser` account to itself on localhost.

Answer (score 30):

Try installing whole SSH package pack:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

I had `ssh` command on my Ubuntu but got the error as you have. After full installation all was resolved.

Comment: This solved it for me, was exactly my situation (I also already had sshd installed and running, out of the box). On Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 20.04. Same situation.

Comment: Thumbs up. Previously I installed `sudo apt-get install openssh-client` on Ubuntu 22.04 and it returned the error. Now with the full SSH package pack install, error gone.

Answer (score 22):

I use a Mac, this worked for me:

Open System Preferences, then search for 'sharing'.

Choose Remote Login, make sure it is on and remember to add required users.[image]

[Got it from here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/smoke/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Enabling-remote-SSH-login-on-Mac-OS-X.html)

Comment: I was having the problem while starting the hadoop, I fixed using this solution.

Answer (score 20):

I did all the suggestion above and it did not work. Then I restart the ssh service and it works. This is what I do:

```
service sshd restart
```

Then I redo

```
ssh localhost
```

Now I can connect to my localhost. Hope it helps

Comment: `ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused`

Answer (score 15):

I used:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Then:

```
ssh localhost
```

Answer (score 13):

Check if this port is open. Maybe your SSH demon is not running. See if sshd is running. If not, then start it.

Comment: i tried giving sudo apt-get install openssh-server command , it started to ask password for hduser , where i didnt create any password for the user, how i can know the default password for hduser

Comment: No it is asking the password for root/ sudo user of linux system where you are installing.

Comment: [root@localhost .ssh]# which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh
[root@localhost .ssh]# which sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd , ssh is already installed in my machine

Comment: then run the sshd demon /bin/etc/init.d sshd start

Comment: sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path , this is message from the path

Comment: any support how to make this up

Answer (score 8):

If you restart service then it will work

```
$ service sshd restart
```

then check

```
$ ssh localhost
```

It will work

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that /etc/hosts.allow contains:

```
ssh:ALL:allow
sshd:ALL:allow
```

OR

```
ssh:localhost:allow
sshd:localhost:allow
```

OR - some other variant

```
ssh:{host1,host2,host3...}:allow
sshd{host1,host2,host3...}:allow
```

INSURE that the first line in the file DOES NOT begin with ALL:ALL:DENY

NOTHING will be able to communicate with the host... on any port.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 4):

For my case(ubuntu 14.04, fresh installed), I just run the following command and it works!

`sudo apt-get install ssh`

Answer (score 4):

For what its worth I got the following error trying to ssh into my local machine, running Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial, from a vm.

```
 ssh: connect to host 192.168.144.18 port 22: Connection refused
```

It got immediately fixed with:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Take note, Before fix: 'which sshd' returned nothing and 'which ssh' returned

```
/usr/bin/ssh
```

And After the fix: 'which sshd' returned

```
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/sshd
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openssh-server
```

I tried all the above mentioned solutions but somehow this directory /var/run/sshd was still missing for me. I have Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. Hope my answer helps if someone has the same issue. 
[ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh)[xenial](/questions/tagged/xenial)

Answer (score 3):

It might be caused by some of the following:

1. SSH Server is not installed (only SSH Client), try: `apt-get install ssh openssh-client openssh-server`
2. Connection is blocked by iptables (Firewall), try: `ufw allow ssh`

Comment: by default ssh is blocked on the firewall, even when installing with openssh enabled

Answer (score 3):

On mac go to system settings->network->sharing and allow remote login.

try ssh localhost

You should be good.

Answer (score 3):

1. Before installing/reinstalling anything check the status of sshd . . .

```sh
sudo systemctl status sshd
```

2. You should see something like . . .

```sh
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; disabled; vendor prese>
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
```

3. Just enable and start sshd

```sh
sudo systemctl enable sshd
sudo systemctl start sshd
```

Comment: in ubuntu: this will work: systemctl enable ssh.service

Answer (score 2):

Actually i solved this,
I just installed shh daemon.

in terminal :

> **sudo apt-get install openssh-server**

Answer (score 2):

If you're certain that you have installed ssh, then it's possible that `ssh` and/or `sshd` has been terminated or the server service hasn't been started. To check whether these processes are running use:

```
//this tells you whether your ssh instance is active/inactive
sudo service ssh status
```

OR

```
//this list all running processes whose names contain the string "ssh"
sudo ps -A | grep ssh
```

It's likely that `ssh` would be active and running but `sshd` would not.
To enable them:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

NB;
- some systems have a restart option but mine didn't

Answer (score 2):

try `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

in first few lies you'll find

Package generated configuration file

See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for

Port xxxxx

change Port xxxxx to "Port 22" and exit vi by saving changes.

restart ssh `sudo service ssh restart`

Answer (score 1):

If you still face problems, try the following:

```
sudo ufw enable    
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

This might work too.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do is to go to terminal

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/hosts

***enter your ip address ipaddress of your pc  localhost 
    ipaddress of your pc  localhost(Edit your pc name with localhost) **
```

and again restart your ssh service using:

```
$ service ssh restart
```

Problem will be resolve.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are using centOS or Red Hat, you should first update SElinux.
Execute the following statement

```
ausearch -c 'sshd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sshd
```

then you need to execute

```
semodule -i my-sshd.pp
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You may should edit your `/etc/hosts`.  For example if my `hostname` is `ub0`, but the `hostname` in `/etc/hosts` is `localhost`, it may occur

```
connect to host ub0 port 22: Connection refused
```

Because the `hostname` in `/etc/hosts` is `localhost` not `ub0`.

So, you should be careful the `hostname` when building up distributed clusters.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux:

1. Remove SSH with the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
   ```
2. Install SSH again with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the configuration in sshd_config ListenAddress 0.0.0.0 update this and restart the sshd service that will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to ping and not able to ssh, then it is a firewall. The firewall on 18.4 (not sure about other versions) in on by default and only allow port 8080.

Here how you fix it

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-firewall-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 0):

Check file /etc/ssh/sshd_config for Port number. Make sure it is 22.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was modifying the ssh config file to the following:

Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 0):

Answer for this question incase you're using a WSL system:

run `sudo service ssh start`

after reinstalling ssh. This helped me.

Answer (score -1):

if youre apache server is not running your local host wont run check that out
there are some articles if you dont get it i will leave a link here ;)

[check this](https://www.cyberpratibha.com/blog/web-server-in-kali-linux/)

I had same error got it done rn

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30439479)

Answer (score -1):

On WSL supported ubuntu I ran

```
service ssh start
```

Then

```
ssh localhost
```

It worked